# How to find camera rotation matrix when axis flips or changes

Tags: geometry, transformation, coordinate-transformation

Let us assume that we have camera extrinsics `[R|t]`(camera-to-world) and a permutation matrix `P` that flips or changes the axis, which may have variants regarding its determinant. For example, this

```
P = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, -1, 0]
]) # (sorry that I'm not writing in consistent manner.)
```

changes points(axis) (x, y, z) to (x, z, -y). This may affect the rotation matrix in new coordinate system, if my guess is correct, so that it results in a new rotation matrix `R'` that decides the orientation of the transformed camera. Is it just `P[R|t]` and I get `R' = PR`? How do I find this?

Answer (score 0):

Fliping odd number of  axises is not rotation ! But that does not matter you can use matrix inverse to compute this so if I see it correctly you have:

```cpp
R' = R*P
```

Where `R'` is your new matrix (fliped) and `R` is original matrix and you want to know the `P` so:

```cpp
           R' =            R*P     // Inverse(R)*
Inverse(R)*R' = Inverse(R)*R*P     
Inverse(R)*R' =              P
```

In case your `R` is orthonormal then Inverse of it is the same as its Transponation which is way faster. If its just ortogonal you can still use `Transpose` instead of `Inverse` but you would need to correct the basis vector lenghts afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but not exactly. I should've stated my problem more precisely. My problem was to find a new rotation matrix ```R_P```, not ```P```. I found out that ```R_P = P*R*inv(P)``` given a permutation matrix ```P``` with negative determinant so it means that the rotation matrix of camera extrinsics also changes when coordinate convention changes by ```P```. (and ```t_P = P*t```, which is obvious.) My new camera extrinsics are then ```[R_P | t_P]```.